# Why wont my LEDs display when Brightness is turned down using Hzellers library?

Tags: pi-2, led, c++

I have 4 16x32 Led matrixs chained to display output from my Raspberry pi using Hzellers led matrix library. Link: https://github.com/hzeller/rpi-rgb-led-matrix. I want it to display at 25 percent brightness, but when the brightness is at 80 it displays just fine. When it is at 75 the boards display nothing. Also when going from 85 to 80, the little snowbird logo text which is / and is blue and green doesnt display, only the red text is. Ill show a picture of this later down. Here is my code. It uses the text-example to take input from my php script to display it on the leds. I run it by the prompt: `(while :; do php snowbirdscrape.php; sleep 10; done) | sudo ./text-example -f fonts/4x6.bdf -z fonts/6x10.bdf -t fonts/5x7.bdf -c4 -y0 -C 255,0,0` My changed text-example code is below.

```
-*- mode: c++; c-basic-offset: 2; indent-tabs-mode: nil; -*-
// Small example how write text.
//
// This code is public domain
// (but note, that the led-matrix library this depends on is GPL v2)

#include "led-matrix.h"
#include "graphics.h"

#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace rgb_matrix;

static int usage(const char *progname) {
  fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s [options]\n", progname);
  fprintf(stderr, "Reads text from stdin and displays it. "
      "Empty string: clear screen\n");
  fprintf(stderr, "Options:\n"
          "\t-f <font-file>: Use given font.\n"
          "\t-r <rows>     : Display rows. 16 for 16x32, 32 for 32x32. "
          "Default: 32\n"
          "\t-P <parallel> : For Plus-models or RPi2: parallel chains. 1..3. "
          "Default: 1\n"
          "\t-c <chained>  : Daisy-chained boards. Default: 1.\n"
          "\t-x <x-origin> : X-Origin of displaying text (Default: 0)\n"
          "\t-y <y-origin> : Y-Origin of displaying text (Default: 0)\n"
          "\t-C <r,g,b>    : Color. Default 255,255,0\n");
  return 1;
}

static bool parseColor(Color *c, const char *str) {
  return sscanf(str, "%hhu,%hhu,%hhu", &c->r, &c->g, &c->b) == 3;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Color color(255, 0, 0);
  const char *bdf_font_file = NULL;
  const char *hello = NULL;
  const char *hello2 = NULL;
  int rows = 16;
  int chain = 4;
  int parallel = 1;
  int x_orig = 0;
  int y_orig = -1;
  Color color2(0,147,208);
  Color color3(178,213,152);

  int opt;
  while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "r:P:c:x:y:f:z:t:C:")) != -1) {
    switch (opt) {
    case 'r': rows = atoi(optarg); break;
    case 'P': parallel = atoi(optarg); break;
    case 'c': chain = atoi(optarg); break;
    case 'x': x_orig = atoi(optarg); break;
    case 'y': y_orig = atoi(optarg); break;
    case 'f': bdf_font_file = strdup(optarg); break;
    case 'z': hello = strdup(optarg); break;
    case 't': hello2 = strdup(optarg); break;
    case 'C':
      if (!parseColor(&color, optarg)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid color spec.\n");
        return usage(argv[0]);
      }
      break;
    default:
      return usage(argv[0]);
    }
  }

  if (bdf_font_file == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Need to specify BDF font-file with -f\n");
    return usage(argv[0]);
  }

  if (hello == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Need to specify BDF font-file with -f\n");
    return usage(argv[0]);
  }

  if (hello2 == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Need to specify BDF font-file with -f\n");
    return usage(argv[0]);
  }


  /*
   * Load font. This needs to be a filename with a bdf bitmap font.
   */
  rgb_matrix::Font font;
  if (!font.LoadFont(bdf_font_file)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't load font '%s'\n", bdf_font_file);
    return usage(argv[0]);
  }
  rgb_matrix::Font font2;
  if (!font2.LoadFont(hello)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't load font '%s'\n", hello);
    return usage(argv[0]);
  }

  rgb_matrix::Font font3;
  if (!font3.LoadFont(hello2)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't load font '%s'\n", hello2);
    return usage(argv[0]);
  }

  if (rows != 16 && rows != 32) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Rows can either be 16 or 32\n");
    return 1;
  }

  if (chain < 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Chain outside usable range\n");
    return 1;
  }
  if (chain > 8) {
    fprintf(stderr, "That is a long chain. Expect some flicker.\n");
  }
  if (parallel < 1 || parallel > 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Parallel outside usable range.\n");
    return 1;
  }

  /*
   * Set up GPIO pins. This fails when not running as root.
   */
  GPIO io;
  if (!io.Init())
    return 1;

  /*
   * Set up the RGBMatrix. It implements a 'Canvas' interface.
   */
  RGBMatrix *canvas = new RGBMatrix(&io, rows, chain, parallel);
  canvas->SetBrightness(75);


  bool all_extreme_colors = true;
  all_extreme_colors &= color.r == 0 || color.r == 255;
  all_extreme_colors &= color.g == 0 || color.g == 255;
  all_extreme_colors &= color.b == 0 || color.b == 255;
  if (all_extreme_colors)
    canvas->SetPWMBits(1);

  const int x = x_orig;
  int y = y_orig;

  if (isatty(STDIN_FILENO)) {
    // Only give a message if we are interactive. If connected via pipe, be quiet
    printf("Enter lines. Full screen or empty line clears screen.\n"
           "Supports UTF-8. CTRL-D for exit.\n");
  }

  char line2[] = "Snowbird";

  char logo1[] = "\\";

  char logo2[] = """/""";

  //char line2[] = "12h 24h 48h CD YTD";

  char line[1024];
  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) {
    const size_t last = strlen(line);
    if (last > 0) line[last - 1] = '\0';  // remove newline.
    bool line_empty = strlen(line) == 0;
    if ((y + font.height() > canvas->height()) || line_empty) {
      canvas->Clear();
      y = y_orig;
    }
    if (line_empty)
      continue;    
    rgb_matrix::DrawText(canvas, font, x, y + font.baseline(), color, line2);
    y += font.height();
    rgb_matrix::DrawText(canvas, font3, 32, 1 + font.baseline(), color2, logo1);
    y += font.height();
    rgb_matrix::DrawText(canvas, font3, 36, 1 + font.baseline(), color3, logo2);
    y += font.height();
    rgb_matrix::DrawText(canvas, font2, x-6, 10 + font.baseline(), color, line);
    y += font.height();
  }

  // Finished. Shut down the RGB matrix.
  canvas->Clear();
  delete canvas;

  return 0;
}
```

The section of code that changes the brightness for the output is:

```
canvas->SetBrightness(75);
```

Could this be code related or would it be because the pi outputs at 3.5 v and the matrices can run 5v? Would be awesome if someone could help me solve this problem!

There is an example program that uses this library, that when ran to display at a 10 percent brightness -b10, a 10 percent brightness is acutely displayed. `./led-matrix -t 10 -D 1 -b10 runtext.ppm` The code to this is at the end of this link: https://github.com/hzeller/rpi-rgb-led-matrix/blob/master/demo-main.cc

Comment: What just happened to these comments? Why where they deleted?

Comment: I deleted them to clean up the thread.